# Library function access-level

Tags: solidity, library, web3.py

I have a contract `A`, which has an instance of contract `B`, i.e., `B b`.

Contract `A` calls a function of contract `B` via the instance, i.e., `b.func()`.

Contract `B` is stateless, i.e., no global non-constant variables.

I therefore decided to redeclare it as a `library`.

After that, when I compile contract `A`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError:
Member "func" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library B)
```

I can resolve the problem by changing the access-level of `func` from `external` to `internal`.

However, that prevents me from calling the function via `Web3` (Python).

Can someone please explain this odd behavior, i.e., why do I need to reduce the function's access-level from `external` to `internal` after I "reduce" the `contract` to a `library`?

UPDATE:

I think I got it:

The `library` code is "embedded" into the `contract` which imports it (like a macro in C if you will).

Then, only functions that are either `private`, `internal` or `public` can be invoked from inside the contract, while `external` functions can be invoked only from outside the contract.

So my question really is:

How can I reconcile the fact that I want these functions to be `internal` when used by a contract, and `external` when accessed via `Web3` (for testing purpose)?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried reproducing the above error, however, I couldn't, could you share your contract code please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `internal` in the library, then create a public function that proxies to the library, like:

```
contract A {
  function func() public returns (?) {
    return b.func();
  }
}
```

Note: I left a `?` in the return type descriptor because the return type of `b.func()` wasn't specified in the question. Fill it in with the type returned by `b.func()`.

Comment: Thought about this, but then - what's the point in having that library to begin with? I might as well just declare it as a contract with a public `func` (instead of a library and a "proxy" contract).